# Requiring unknown module "11" error on iOS simulator

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

When I run the react native project with `react-native run-ios`.It shows the following error on my iOS simulator.On my android simulator, it is totally ok.I have deleted node module and reinstalled.But the error is still there.I don't want to entirely delete my ios/build folder since I have manually added library dependencies in there and that third party libraries were working properly in my react native project.Can someone help me with this?

Error Message

> Requiring unknown module "11".If you are sure the module is there, try
>   restarting Metro Bundler.You may also want to run yarn or npm install(
>   depending on your environment ).

[image: Error Message on iOS]

package.json

```
{
  "name": "AwwsomeProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-native": "0.55.4",
    "react-native-navigation": "^1.1.473",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "23.2.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "jest": "23.2.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

Comment: have u try npm install again?

Answer (score 31):

Restarting packager fixed my issue.

Comment: I'v had the same issue with different module . relaunching the packager and npm start is the only thing that worked for me

Comment: "Packager" meaning Metro bundler?

Comment: In root with terminal run `rm -r node_module`, then `npm i` and will work

Answer (score 12):

I fixed the issue with the instructions from the following page:

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/troubleshooting#content

Basically it asks you to terminate the processes running on a specific port.

Run the following command to find the id for the process that is listening on port 8081:

```
$ sudo lsof -i :8081
```

Then run the following to terminate the process:

```
$ kill -9 <PID>
```

Answer (score 3):

I just killed all node processes

```
killall node
```

and launched again

Comment: I got this issue when I added a number to the name of one of my modules. Changing it to from "Step1" to "StepOne", and running "killall node" solved my issue

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. Running `npm install` or `yarn install` should fix the issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem while working with my react native app and expo. Same screen with 'Requiring Unknown Module 1".

This is how I fixed it:

- I closed Expo
- I closed the Metro bundler on my local host
- I closed the packager on my terminal with Ctlr + C
- I restarted with npm start
- I relaunched the project on Expo.

It worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

I had this issue on Android (React-Native-CLI).
Terminating the application and restarting metro server absolutely solved the issue.

```
yarn react-native start
```

Answer (score 1):

Using yarn, I did the following (for Android emulation):

From root directory in your project:

1. `cd android`
2. `./gradlew clean`
3. `cd ..`
4. `yarn start --reset-cache`
5. `yarn android`

Comment: The question clearly says its happening in ios.

Answer (score 1):

- Looks like `node` and the application inside simulator hangs sometimes. I encountered this several times on macOS / iOS.
- `yarn install` did not help.
- restarting simulation with `expo run:ios` / `yarn start` / `yarn ios` did not help.
- What helped was `killall node` and `killall <your_mobile_app_name>`.

Answer (score 0):

`npm run ios` fixed for me after `npm start`